# Why does the knockout binding pass the span element's id rather than the anchor element's id?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Consider the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="aElement" data-bind="click: printId">
   <span id="spanElement">Click Me</span>
</a>
```

When I click on the link, I have a **printId** function that is called:

```
printId: function (item, event) {

    vm.textTest(event.target.id);
}
```

I would expect that the event.target.id value to be **aElement**, since that is the element that I have my click binding set to, but instead it is **spanElement**. Is there a reason why this is the case?

I'm guessing it is because that the actual "substance" that I am clicking on is the span element, but I still think it would make better sense to grab the anchor element instead from a coding standpoint. After all, I may have multiple elements inside that anchor tag and I may want to consistently get a single id every time rather than whatever id might be thrown my way based on where the user clicks inside the anchor tag.

However, this may be a JavaScript issue rather than a knockout issue. Any thoughts?

Here is a fiddle:

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dUULM/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event from the span bubbles up the DOM. Use event.currentTarget as that will refer to the element the event handler has been attached to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget

Answer (score 2):

It is a javascript issue - the span is the `event.target`, since it's the actual (innermost) item you clicked on.

try this - add some text outside the span and then click on that - you'll see the event.target.id go to aElement.

Use `event.currentTarget` if you want the item you actually placed the binding on. `event.currentTarget` is the element listening for the event, `event.target` is the element which *received* the event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is directly related to javascript, not to knockout. Knockout just passes the actual javascript event as an argument. You can check it by using vanilla javascript:

```
<a href="#" id="aElement" data-bind="click: printId"><span id="spanElement">Click Me</span> test</a>

function test(e) {
 alert(e.target.id + " / " + e.currentTarget.id);
}
document.getElementById('aElement').onclick = test;
```

If you click on "test", the target id will be the "a" id. But if you click on "Click Me", you will get the span id.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/7CCfp/2/